# Jetty home system property is not set

Tags: java, jetty, system-properties

I'm trying to use the system property in my jetty config as the following:

```
<SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="" />/etc/jetty7/context
```

But the `jetty.home` always returns empty. How can i set this variable and point it to where?

I need this for an context path.

My jetty home folder is `D:\Developer Tools\jetty-6.1.26`. Does it need to point to this folder? If so, how can i do this? Do i need to use Windows global variables?

I'm using the `org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration` class from `org.mortbay.jetty`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`jetty.home` is set by Jetty's start mechanism.

You are using Jetty 6.1.26 *(note: Jetty 6.x has been deprecated and end of life'd back in 2010)*

While I don't know how Jetty 6 worked, I do know how Jetty 7/8/9 work in this respect.

**Update: Aug 2019:** Jetty 9.4.x is the current stable & actively supported version mainline of Jetty.

The Jetty start mechanism (module: [`/jetty-start/`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-start?id=jetty-7.6.11.v20130520). aka `start.jar`) would establish the `jetty.home` property [based on a set of rules](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-start/src/main/resources/org/eclipse/jetty/start/start.config?id=jetty-7.6.11.v20130520#n63) in the [`start.config`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-start/src/main/resources/org/eclipse/jetty/start/start.config?id=jetty-7.6.11.v20130520) (a file present in the `start.jar`) and then use the `org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration` class ([also defined in the `start.config`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-start/src/main/resources/org/eclipse/jetty/start/start.config?id=jetty-7.6.11.v20130520#n71)) to establish a set of properties in the `XmlConfiguration` object, then load the XML files declared on the command line and `start.ini`.

**Problem #1: Mixed Jetty Versions**

You have a mix of Jetty versions, that can work, but not across Jetty 6 (as seen in your declared jetty home folder of `D:\Developer Tools\jetty-6.1.26`) and Jetty 7 (as seen in your `/etc/jetty7/context` declaration).  They are 100% incompatible.

**Problem #2: Bad XML Syntax Use**

Your XML syntax for working with paths is wrong.

**Your Syntax**

```xml
<Set name="monitoredDir">
    <SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="" />/etc/jetty7/context
</Set>
```

1. It is a mix of relative and absolute paths and will not work.
2. You must always declare a default value on `<SystemProperty>` use when working with paths. (empty default is invalid)

**Correct Syntax for Relative Paths**

```xml
<Set name="monitoredDir">
    <SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="." />etc/jetty7/context
</Set>
```

If your `jetty.home` is `D:\Developer Tools\jetty-distribution-7.6.11.v20130520`, then this will point to `D:\Developer Tools\jetty-distribution-7.6.11.v20130520\etc\jetty7\context`

If you don't declare `jetty.home` before using `XmlConfiguration` then the default value will be used, the `"."` it will be translated as whatever your current working directory is (also known as `System.getProperty("user.dir")`) plus the hardcoded relative path you specified.  If `user.dir` is `D:\Code\MyProject`, then the result would be `D:\Code\MyProject\etc\jetty7\context`

**Correct Syntax for Absolute Paths**

```xml
<Set name="monitoredDir">/etc/jetty7/context</Set>
```

This syntax could care less about `jetty.home` and the result will always be `/etc/jetty7/context` on unix and (highly likely to be) `C:\etc\jetty7\context` on windows.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You're totally right on the about the mixed versions and the default path. It turned out i had a enter between the SystemPropoerty and the etc/jetty...